# Force/Convince/Trick GCC into Unrolling _Longer_ Loops?

Tags: c, gcc, loop-unrolling

How do I convince GCC to unroll a loop where the number of iterations is known, but large?

I'm compiling with `-O3`.

The real code in question is more complex, of course, but here's a boiled-down example that has the same behavior:

```
int const constants[] = { 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144 };

int get_sum_1()
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < CONSTANT_COUNT; ++i)
    {
        total += constants[i];
    }
    return total;
}
```

...if `CONSTANT_COUNT` is defined as 8 (or less) then GCC will unroll the loop, propagate the constants, and reduce the entire function down to a simple `return <value>;`. If, on the other hand, `CONSTANT_COUNT` is 9 (or greater) then the loop is not unrolled, and GCC produces a binary which loops, reads the constants, and adds them at run-time - even though, in theory, the function could still be optimized down to just returning a constant. (Yes, I've looked at the decompiled the binary.)

If I *manually* unroll the loop, like this:

```
int get_sum_2()
{
    int total = 0;
    total += constants[0];
    total += constants[1];
    total += constants[2];
    total += constants[3];
    total += constants[4];
    total += constants[5];
    total += constants[6];
    total += constants[7];
    total += constants[8];
    //total += constants[9];
    return total;
}
```

Or this:

```
#define ADD_CONSTANT(z, v, c) total += constants[v];

int get_sum_2()
{
    int total = 0;
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(CONSTANT_COUNT, ADD_CONSTANT, _)
    return total;
}
```

...then the function is optimized down to returning a constant. So, GCC appears to be able to handle the constant propagation for larger loops, once unrolled; the hang-up appears to be just getting GCC to consider unrolling the longer loop in the first place.

However, neither hand-unrolling nor `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` are viable options, because there are *some* cases where `CONSTANT_COUNT` is a run-time expression, and the *same* code still needs to work correctly for those cases. (Performance isn't as critical in those cases.)

I'm working in C (not C++) so neither template meta-programming nor `constexpr` are available to me.

I've tried `-funroll-loops`, `-funroll-all-loops`, `-fpeel-loops`, and setting large values for `max-unrolled-insns`, `max-average-unrolled-insns`, `max-unroll-times`, `max-peeled-insns`, `max-peel-times`, `max-completely-peeled-insns`, and `max-completely-peel-times`, none of which seem to make a difference.

I'm using GCC 4.8.2, on Linux, x86_64.

Any ideas? Is there a flag or parameter I'm missing...?

Comment: So, you basically want GCC to figure out what the loop would compute, and just use that number; you don't really care if it mentally unrolls the loop or not, as long as it boils it down to a constant, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this workaround is applicable to your actual problem but I found that GCC 4.9.0 20140604 (prerelease) on an x86_64 running Parabola GNU/Linux unrolls the following loop up to and including `CONSTANT_COUNT == 33`.

```c
int
get_sum()
{
  int total = 0;
  int i, j, k = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
    {
      for (i = 0; i < CONSTANT_COUNT / 2; ++i)
        {
          total += constants[k++];
        }
    }
  if (CONSTANT_COUNT % 2)
    total += constants[k];
  return total;
}
```

I have only passed it the `-O3` flag.  The assembly code for `get_sum` is really just

```
movl $561, %eax
ret
```

I did not try but maybe the pattern can be extended even further.

It seems odd to me that this works since – at least to my human eyes – the code looks much more complex now.  Unfortunately, it is a rather intrusive way to force the unrolling.  A compiler flag would have been much nicer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this workaround doesn't seem to work for my _real_ code, but it's interesting that it works for the simplified code here. What's really interesting is that this (well, something very similar to this - doing the body twice per loop iteration, anyway) lets this simple example get optimized all the way up to `CONSTANT_COUNT`==256, and maybe higher, but that's as high as I tried.

Answer (score 2):

GCC has a big lot of obscure parameters and program arguments regarding loop unrolling (and [optimizations](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)). You could play with `-funroll-loops`, `-funroll-all-loops`, `--param` *name=value*, (e.g. with *name* being `max-unroll-times` ....) etc.

<sup>Order of arguments to `gcc` matters a lot. You probably want to put `-O3` first, and the weird options above after it.</sup>

However, increasing the unrolling will not always improve the performance.

Last but not least, you could code your own GCC plugin which would change the unrolling criteria.

*Cleverly* using `__builtin_prefetch` might improve performance, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460606/841108) (but using it *carelessly* will *degrade* performance)

You need to benchmark. My feeling is that premature micro-optimization is a big lose of your time.