# C compiler optimize loop by running it

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, optimization, compiler-optimization

Can a C compiler ever optimize a loop by running it?

For example:

```
int num[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, i;
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(num)/sizeof(num[0]); i++) {
  if(num[i] > 6) {
    printf("Error in data\n");
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

Instead of running this each time the program is executed, can the compiler simply run this and optimize it away?

Comment: Well, you can check with ex. `gcc -S`. This is called 'loop unrolling'; the compiler effectively copy+pastes the loop body, changing the `i` variable to a constant each time. AFAIK it works well for small loops, and can allow other optimizations to happen (such as eliminating the dead code that the `if` branch would generate).

Comment: Try compiling with `-S -funroll-loops` and check the output. "Running" the loop isn't quite the right term, though - it's not like the code is actually executed.

Comment: Look up 'profile-based optimization' or PBO (aka 'profile-guided optimization' or PGO). Yes, it is possible for optimizers to optimize based on the observed performance of the program running.  See also 'link-time optimization' (LTO) and 'whole-program optimization'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's have a look… (This really is the only way to tell.)

Fist, I've converted your snippet into something we can actually try to compile and run and saved it in a file named `main.c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int
f()
{
  const int num[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(num) / sizeof(num[0]); i++)
    {
      if (num[i] > 6)
        {
          printf("Error in data\n");
          return 1;
        }
    }
  return 0;
}

int
main()
{
  return f();
}
```

Running `gcc -S -O3 main.c` produces the following assembly file (in `main.s`).

```
        .file   "main.c"
        .section        .text.unlikely,"ax",@progbits
.LCOLDB0:
        .section        .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.LHOTB0:
        .p2align 4,,15
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB22:
        .cfi_startproc
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE22:
        .size   main, .-main
        .section        .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE0:
        .section        .text.startup
.LHOTE0:
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 5.1.0"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Even if you don't know assembly, you'll notice that the string `"Error in data\n"` is not present in the file so, apparently, some kind of optimization must have taken place.

If we look closer at the machine instructions generated for the `main` function,

```
xorl    %eax, %eax
ret
```

We can see that all it does is XOR'ing the EAX register with itself (which always results in zero) and writing that value into EAX.  Then it returns again.  The EAX register is used to hold the return value.  As we can see, the `f` function was completely optimized away.

Comment: Interestingly, clang (tested on 3.5.1) can achieve this with a mere `-O1`.

Comment: So say you have a deterministic program that takes a long time to run (perhaps `num` is very long, yet compiled in). At what point does the compiler say "I'll optimize this now", vs "Let it run"?

Comment: @Ariel There is no reliable way to tell other than looking at the assembly code actually generated for your program and if you change a tiny bit, something different might happen.  At least unless you know intimate details of your compiler.  Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25878821/1392132) and my answer there for an example how tricky it can become to reason about what optimization the compiler will ultimately decide to perform.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The C compiler [unrolls loops automatically with options -O3 and -Otime](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124222660.htm).

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to unroll any loops here. All that's required is to notice that the code does nothing.

Comment: Isn't unrolling the loop part of the process that the compiler does to see that the code does nothing?

Comment: I don't see why. You can realize easily that the loop body is empty (since the condition is always false) without unrolling...

Comment: Yes, I can realise it, but I am not a compiler.  How does the compiler realise it?

Comment: If even you can realize it, surely it's possible to program a machine to realize the same thing :-)

Comment: The point I am trying to get at is how compilers actually do their optimisation, not how you can imagine that they might do it differently!

Comment: Well, hundreds of people have spent decades developing the knowledge and sophistication for that, so don't expect the answer in a comment. You can read academic literature on compiler design, or study the implementations of open-source compilers at your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the compiler, but using gcc with -O3 *and* taking the size calculation outside the for *maybe* it could do a little adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers can do even better than that.  Not only can compilers examine the effect of running code "forward", but the Standard even allows them to work code logic *in reverse* in situations involving potential Undefined Behavior. For example, given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int ch = getchar();
  int q;
  if (ch == 'Z')
    q=5;
  printf("You typed %c and the magic value is %d", ch, q);
  return 0;
}
```

a compiler would be entitled to assume that the program will never receive any input which would cause the `printf` to be reached without `q` having received a value; since the only input character which would cause `q` to receive a value would be `'Z'`, a compiler could thus legitimately replace the code with:

```
int main(void)
{
  getchar();
  printf("You typed Z and the magic value is 5");
}
```

If the user types `Z`, the behavior of the original program will be well-defined, and the behavior of the latter will match it.  If the user types anything else, the original program will invoke Undefined Behavior and, as a consequence, the Standard will impose no requirements on what the compiler may do.  A compiler will be entitled to do anything it likes, including producing the same result as would be produced by typing `Z`.

Comment: But this doesn't really answer the OP's question.

Comment: What "second `printf`"? There's only one in each code snippet.

Comment: @ThePcLuddite: Is that a little better?

Comment: @void_ptr: Mea culpa.  I simplified my example and neglected to fix the text to match.