# is register data type variables are limited?

Tags: c, linux, storage, cpu-registers

i totally stucked with this question, i had heard that there are **5 to 10** variables only can declare having **datatype** of register. i wish to know how many **register datatype variables** would be declare.it is pretty to seem. but this level of understanding we required while executing a programs.otherwise we mightstuck at runtime while execution thanks for your answers in advance

1).is registers(for datatypes) are vary to different types of compilers/machines??
2).how many register datatype variables could we pick ?
3).what are all these registers?(i mean cpu reg, memory reg, general purpose reg???)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`register` is no more a useful keyword in C programs compiled by a recent C [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (e.g. recent versions of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)).

Today, it simply means that a variable qualified as `register` cannot be the operand of the `&` unary *address-of* operator (notice that `register` is a qualifier like `const` or `volatile` are, not a data type like `int`).

<sup>In the 1990s, `register` was then an important keyword for compilers.</sup>

The compiler (when optimizing) does a pretty good job about [register allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation) and spilling.

Try to compile your favorite C function with e.g. `gcc -Wall -O2 -fverbose-asm -S`; you'll get an assembly file suffixed `.s` and you could look inside it; the compiler is doing pretty well about register allocation.

Notice that GCC provides language [extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html) to put a few global (or local) variables in [explicit registers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Reg-Vars.html#Explicit-Reg-Vars). This is rarely useful, and it is target processor and ABI specific.

BTW, on desktop or laptop processors, the [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) matters a lot more than the registers (see references and hints in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26820202/841108) to another question).

Answer (score 1):

In C there is no way to explicitely define variable in [CPU registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register). You may barely hint a compiler with `register` specifier, but there is no point to do it nowadays, as compilers have [sophisticated optimizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler), which takes care of registers allocation.

Answer (score 0):

do not use register. The optomizer will do a better job