# How can I ivestigate use of the register keyword in C?

Tags: c, cpu, cpu-registers

From what I have read, I know that the `register` keyword is almost always optimised by the modern compilers. Some sources claim that it shouldn't be used anymore, as the compiler will optimise the code better than the programmer in most cases.

Therefore I have these three questions:

1. Is tat keyword still being used in some applications?
2. How does GCC handle `register` keyword?
3. If it has effect on the performance of my code, how can I investigate the use of `register`? (Can I see where it the `register` variable stored? Can I force the compiler the interpret the keyword the way I want declared the variable, without any optimisations?)

Comment: I think the dupe-linking by @paulr is correct. To answer your q's 1. Maybe. 2. Just like all other compilars. 3. you cannot check the address of a register.

Comment: "Maybe" is not the answer for question 1 I was looking for.

Comment: register will not, generally speaking, do anything to the generated code.

Comment: I recommend exploring things like this on gcc.godbolt.org, as an example http://goo.gl/Zq5o0g

Comment: As well as numerous duplicates, the question has other problems, e.g. it breaks the "one question per question" rule, and there doesn't seem to be a specific problem here that you are trying to solve, just the beginning of an open-ended discussion on the history, rationale and internal workings of the register keyword. Perhaps you could narrow the question down to a specific problem and try again?

Comment: @PaulR Can you please delete the question then? I will ask more specific question(s) on the same topic somewhere in the future.

Comment: @REACHUS: I'm not a moderator, so I can't delete the question, and it has a useful answer now, so it wouldn't be a good idea to delete it anyway. It should probably just be put "on hold" for posterity, and if you have any remaining specific question(s) then post it/them as new question(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today, with optimizing compilers (like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with `-O1` at least), the `register` keyword is indeed deprecated. Its only meaning is to forbid taking the address of such a declared variable.

In other words,

```
  register int r;
  printf("r@%p\n", &r); // WRONG: address of register variable
```

should not compile.

GCC also provides as an *extension* (also understood by [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)) [variables in specified register](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Reg-Vars.html#Explicit-Reg-Vars).

You might look inside the assembler code (file `*.s`), e.g. produced with `gcc -Wall -O2 -S -fverbose-asm`...

BTW, on current machines, the [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) and the [locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) of data matters a lot regarding to performance, probably much more than register usage (of course, assuming [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) are enabled in your compiler). Read also about [register renaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460606/841108) (related to prefetching).