# why does GCC __builtin_prefetch not improve performance?

Tags: c, performance, gcc, prefetch

I'm writing a program to analyze a graph of social network. It means the program needs a lot of random memory accesses. It seems to me prefetch should help. Here is a small piece of the code of reading values from neighbors of a vertex.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < v.get_num_edges(); i++) {
    unsigned int id = v.neighbors[i];
    res += neigh_vals[id];
}
```

I transform the code above to the one as below and prefetch the values of the neighbors of a vertex.

```
int *neigh_vals = new int[num_vertices];

for (size_t i = 0; i < v.get_num_edges(); i += 128) {
    size_t this_end = std::min(v.get_num_edges(), i + 128);
    for (size_t j = i; j < this_end; j++) {
        unsigned int id = v.neighbors[j];
        __builtin_prefetch(&neigh_vals[id], 0, 2);
    }
    for (size_t j = i; j < this_end; j++) {
        unsigned int id = v.neighbors[j];
        res += neigh_vals[id];
    }
}
```

In this C++ code, I didn't override any operators.

Unfortunately, the code doesn't really improve the performance. I wonder why. Apparently, hardware prefetch doesn't work in this case because the hardware can't predict the memory location.

I wonder if it's caused by GCC optimization. When I compile the code, I enable -O3. I really hope prefetch can further improve performance even when -O3 is enabled. Does -O3 optimization fuse the two loops in this case? Can -O3 enable prefetch in this case by default?

I use gcc version 4.6.3 and the program runs on Intel Xeon E5-4620.

Thanks,
Da

Comment: What is `get_neighbor` doing? What is the type of `neigh_vals`? What is `vertex_id_t`? What is `v`? Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8460606/841108) to a *related* question

Comment: It looks like you're prefetching in one loop and hoping that data will still be available in the next loop.  That's unlikely to help and probably hurts.

Comment: And which version of `gcc`, which processor ? You need to edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Aside: Is `v.get_num_edges()` invariant throughout the `for` loop?  Looks like you can assign it to a variable rather than invoking it every time through the top of the loop.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, some recent versions of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (e.g. 4.9 in march 2015) are able to issue some `PREFETCH` instruction when optimizing with `-O3` (even without any explicit `__builtin_prefetch`)

We don't know what `get_neighbor` is doing, and what are the types of `v` and `neigh_val`.

And prefetching is *not* always profitable. Adding explicit `__builtin_prefetch` can *slow down* your code. **You need to measure.**

As [Retired Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920069/retired-ninja) commented, prefetching in one loop and hoping data would be cached in the following loop (further down in your source code) is wrong.

You might perhaps try instead

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < v.get_num_edges(); i++) {
  fg::vertex_id_t id = v.get_neighbor(i);
  __builtin_prefetch (neigh_val[v.get_neighbor(i+4)]);
  res += neigh_vals[id];
}
```

<sup>You could empirically replace the `4` with whatever appropriate constant is the best.</sup>

But I guess that the `__builtin_prefetch` above is useless (since the compiler is probably able to add it by itself) and it could harm (or even crash the program, when computing its argument gives undefined behavior, e.g. if `v.get_neighbor(i+4)` is undefined; however prefetching an address outside of your address space won't harm -but could slow down your program). **Please benchmark.**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460606/841108) to a related question.

Notice that in C++ all of `[]`, `get_neighbor` could be overloaded and becomes very complex operations, so we cannot guess!

And there are cases where the hardware is limiting performance, whatever `__builtin_prefetch` you add (and adding them could *hurt* performance)

BTW, you might pass `-O3 -mtune=native -fdump-tree-ssa -S -fverbose-asm` to understand more what the compiler is doing (and look inside generated dump files and assembler files); also, it does happen that `-O3` produces slightly slower code than what `-O2` gives.

You could consider explicit [multithreading](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/), [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP), [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) if you have time to waste on optimization. Remember that **premature optimization is evil**. Did you benchmark, did you profile your entire application?

Comment: Just to be clear, “or even crash the program” does not mean prefetching generates faults if the address is invalid—but the address expression itself must be valid.