# Unexpectedly poor and weirdly bimodal performance for store loop on Intel Skylake

Tags: performance, assembly, optimization, x86, x86-64

I'm seeing unexpectedly poor performance for a simple store loop which has two stores: one with a forward stride of 16 byte and one that's always to the same location<sup>1</sup>, like this:

```
volatile uint32_t value;

void weirdo_cpp(size_t iters, uint32_t* output) {

    uint32_t x = value;
    uint32_t          *rdx = output;
    volatile uint32_t *rsi = output;
    do {
        *rdx    = x;
        *rsi = x;

        rdx += 4;  // 16 byte stride
    } while (--iters > 0);
}
```

In assembly this loop probably<sup>3</sup> looks like:

```
weirdo_cpp:

...

align 16
.top:
    mov    [rdx], eax  ; stride 16
    mov    [rsi], eax  ; never changes

    add    rdx, 16

    dec    rdi
    jne    .top

    ret
```

When the memory region accessed is in L2 I would expect this to run at less than 3 cycles per iteration. The second store just keeps hitting the same location and should add about a cycle. The first store implies bringing in a line from L2 and hence also evicting a line *once every 4 iterations*. I'm not sure how you evaluate the L2 cost, but even if you conservatively estimate that the L1 can only do one of the following every cycle: (a) commit a store or (b) receive a line from L2 or (c) evict a line to L2, you'd get something like 1 + 0.25 + 0.25 = 1.5 cycles for the stride-16 store stream.

Indeed, you comment out one store you get ~1.25 cycles per iteration for the first store only, and ~1.01 cycles per iteration for the second store, so 2.5 cycles per iteration seems like a conservative estimate.

The actual performance is very odd, however. Here's a typical run of the test harness:

```
Estimated CPU speed:  2.60 GHz
output size     :   64 KiB
output alignment:   32
 3.90 cycles/iter,  1.50 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 3.90 cycles/iter,  1.50 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 3.90 cycles/iter,  1.50 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 3.89 cycles/iter,  1.49 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 3.90 cycles/iter,  1.50 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 4.73 cycles/iter,  1.81 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 7.33 cycles/iter,  2.81 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 7.33 cycles/iter,  2.81 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 7.34 cycles/iter,  2.81 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 7.26 cycles/iter,  2.80 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 7.28 cycles/iter,  2.80 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 7.31 cycles/iter,  2.81 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 7.29 cycles/iter,  2.81 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 7.28 cycles/iter,  2.80 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 7.29 cycles/iter,  2.80 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 7.27 cycles/iter,  2.80 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 7.30 cycles/iter,  2.81 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 7.30 cycles/iter,  2.81 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 7.28 cycles/iter,  2.80 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
 7.28 cycles/iter,  2.80 ns/iter, cpu before: 0, cpu after: 0
```

Two things are weird here.

First are the bimodal timings: there is a *fast mode* and a *slow mode*. We start out in *slow mode* taking about 7.3 cycles per iteration, and at some point transition to about 3.9 cycles per iteration. This behavior is consistent and reproducible and the two timings are always quite consistent clustered around the two values. The transition shows up in both directions from *slow mode* to *fast mode* and the other way around (and sometimes multiple transitions in one run).

The other weird thing is the really bad performance. Even in *fast mode*, at about 3.9 cycles the performance is much worse than the 1.0 + 1.3 = 2.3 cycles worst cast you'd expect from adding together the each of the cases with a single store (and assuming that absolutely zero worked can be overlapped when both stores are in the loop). In *slow mode*, performance is terrible compared to what you'd expect based on first principles: it is taking 7.3 cycles to do 2 stores, and if you put it in L2 store bandwidth terms, that's roughly **29 cycles** per L2 store (since we only store one full cache line every 4 iterations).

Skylake is [recorded](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/skylake_(client)) as having a 64B/cycle throughput between L1 and L2, which is *way* higher than the observed throughput here (about 2 bytes/cycle  in *slow mode*).

**What explains the poor throughput and bimodal performance and can I avoid it?**

I'm also curious if this reproduces on other architectures and even on other Skylake boxes. Feel free to include local results in the comments.

You can find the [test code and harness on github](https://github.com/travisdowns/bimodal-performance). There is a `Makefile` for Linux or Unix-like platforms, but it should be relatively easy to build on Windows too. If you want to run the `asm` variant you'll need `nasm` or `yasm` for the assembly<sup>4</sup> - if you don't have that you can just try the C++ version.

### Eliminated Possibilities

Here are some possibilities that I considered and largely eliminated. Many of the possibilities are eliminated by the simple fact that you see the performance transition randomly *in the middle of the benchmarking loop*, when many things simply haven't changed (e.g., if it was related to the output array alignment, it couldn't change in the middle of a run since the same buffer is used the entire time). I'll refer to this as the **default elimination** below (even for things that are default elimination there is often another argument to be made).

- Alignment factors: the output array is 16 byte aligned, and I've tried up to 2MB alignment without change. Also eliminated by the *default elimination*.
- Contention with other processes on the machine: the effect is observed more or less identically on an idle machine and even on a heavily loaded one (e.g., using `stress -vm 4`). The benchmark itself should be completely core-local anyways since it fits in L2, and `perf` confirms there are very few L2 misses per iteration (about 1 miss every 300-400 iterations, probably related to the `printf` code).
- TurboBoost: TurboBoost is completely disabled, confirmed by three different MHz readings.
- Power-saving stuff:  The performance governor is `intel_pstate` in `performance` mode. No frequency variations are observed during the test (CPU stays essentially locked at 2.59 GHz).
- TLB effects: The effect is present even when the output buffer is located in a 2 MB huge page. In any case, the 64 4k TLB entries more than cover the 128K output buffer. `perf` doesn't report any particularly weird TLB behavior.
- 4k aliasing: older, more complex versions of this benchmark did show some 4k aliasing but this has been eliminated since there are *no loads* in the benchmark (it's loads that might incorrectly alias earlier stores).  Also eliminated by the *default elimination*.
- L2 associativity conflicts: eliminated by the *default elimination* and by the fact that this doesn't go away even with 2MB pages, where we can be sure the output buffer is laid out linearly in physical memory.
- Hyperthreading effects: HT is disabled.
- Prefetching: Only two of the prefetchers could be involved here (the "DCU", aka L1<->L2 prefetchers), since all the data lives in L1 or L2, but the performance is the same with all prefetchers enabled or all disabled.
- Interrupts: no correlation between interrupt count and slow mode. There is a limited number of total interrupts, mostly clock ticks.

### toplev.py

I used [toplev.py](https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools/wiki/toplev-manual) which implements Intel's [Top Down](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune-amplifier-help-tuning-applications-using-a-top-down-microarchitecture-analysis-method) analysis method, and to no surprise it identifies the benchmark as store bound:

```
BE             Backend_Bound:                                                      82.11 % Slots      [  4.83%]
BE/Mem         Backend_Bound.Memory_Bound:                                         59.64 % Slots      [  4.83%]
BE/Core        Backend_Bound.Core_Bound:                                           22.47 % Slots      [  4.83%]
BE/Mem         Backend_Bound.Memory_Bound.L1_Bound:                                 0.03 % Stalls     [  4.92%]
    This metric estimates how often the CPU was stalled without
    loads missing the L1 data cache...
    Sampling events:  mem_load_retired.l1_hit:pp mem_load_retired.fb_hit:pp
BE/Mem         Backend_Bound.Memory_Bound.Store_Bound:                             74.91 % Stalls     [  4.96%] <==
    This metric estimates how often CPU was stalled  due to
    store memory accesses...
    Sampling events:  mem_inst_retired.all_stores:pp
BE/Core        Backend_Bound.Core_Bound.Ports_Utilization:                         28.20 % Clocks     [  4.93%]
BE/Core        Backend_Bound.Core_Bound.Ports_Utilization.1_Port_Utilized:         26.28 % CoreClocks [  4.83%]
    This metric represents Core cycles fraction where the CPU
    executed total of 1 uop per cycle on all execution ports...
               MUX:                                                                 4.65 %           
    PerfMon Event Multiplexing accuracy indicator
```

This doesn't really shed much light: we already knew it must be the stores messing things up, but why? [Intel's description](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune-amplifier-help-store-bound) of the condition doesn't say much.

[Here's](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/532346) a reasonable summary of some of the issues involved in L1-L2 interaction.

---

**Update Feb 2019:** I cannot no longer reproduce the "bimodal" part of the performance: for me, on the same i7-6700HQ box, the performance is now *always* very slow in the same cases the slow and very slow bimodal performance applies, i.e., with results around 16-20 cycles per line, like this:

[image: Everything slow now]

This change seems to have been introduced in the August 2018 Skylake microcode update, revision 0xC6. The prior microcode, 0xC2 shows the original behavior described in the question.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is a greatly simplified MCVE of my original loop, which was at least 3 times the size and which did lots of additional work, but exhibited exactly the same performance as this simple version, bottlenecked on the same mysterious issue.

<sup>3</sup> In particular, it looks *exactly* like this if you write the assembly by hand, or if you compile it with `gcc -O1` (version 5.4.1), and probably most reasonable compilers (`volatile` is used to avoid sinking the mostly-dead second store outside the loop).

<sup>4</sup> No doubt you could convert this to MASM syntax with a few minor edits since the assembly is so trivial. Pull requests accepted.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161567/discussion-on-question-by-beeonrope-unexpectedly-poor-and-weirdly-bimodal-perfor).

Comment: Thanks, @BhargavRao for restoring the previously-deleted comments with some useful guesses and discussion into a chat link.  (Future readers: some of the stuff about prefetch is now included in the question.  But there's some stuff about L2 perf counters that was still being discussed which is now only in chat.)

Comment: What specific processor is this (e.g. `lscpu | grep "Model name"`)?  I have been running your test on a Xeon Platinum 8180 processor and do not observe this behavior.  I observe 3.85+/-0.01 cycles/iter consistently.

Comment: @Jeff - this was an i7-6700HQ. There is a longer [thread on it on RWT](https://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=173441), with some results on other systems: people saw the same on Sandy Bridge and Broadwell. I don't think we had any SkylakeX results though, so thanks for the update!

Answer (score 13):

What I've found so far. Unfortunately it doesn't really offer an explanation for the poor performance, and not at all for the bimodal distribution, but is more a set of rules for when you might see the performance and notes on mitigating it:

- The store throughput into L2 appears to be at most one 64-byte cache-line per three cycles<sup>0</sup>, putting a ~21 bytes per cycle upper limit on store throughput. Said another way, series of stores that miss in L1 and hit in L2 will take *at least* three cycles per cache line touched.
- Above that baseline there is a significant penalty when stores that hit in L2 are *interleaved* with stores to *a different cache line* (regardless of whether those stores hit in L1 or L2).
- The penalty is apparently somewhat larger for stores that are *nearby* (but still not in the same cache line).
- The bimodal performance is at least superficially related to above effect since in the non-interleaving case it does not appear to occur, although I don't have a further explanation for it.
- If you ensure the cache line is already in L1 before the store, by prefetch or a dummy load, the slow performance disappears and the performance is no longer bimodal.

### Details and Pictures

#### 64-byte Stride

The original question arbitrarily used a stride of 16, but let's start with probably the simplest case: a stride of 64, i.e., one full cache line. As it turns out the various effects are visible with any stride, but 64 ensures an L2 cache miss on every stride and so removes some variables.

Let's also remove the second store for now - so we're just testing a single 64-byte strided store over 64K of memory:

```
top:
mov    BYTE PTR [rdx],al
add    rdx,0x40
sub    rdi,0x1
jne    top
```

Running this in the same harness as above, I get about 3.05 cycles/store<sup>2</sup>, although there is quite a bit of variance compared to what I'm used to seeing ( - you can even find a 3.0 in there).

So we know already we probably aren't going to do better than this for sustained stores purely to L2<sup>1</sup>. While Skylake apparently has a 64 byte throughput between L1 and L2, in the case of a stream of stores, that bandwidth has to be shared for both evictions from L1, and to load the new line into L1. 3 cycles seems reasonable if it takes say 1 cycle each to (a) evict the dirty victim line from L1 to L2 (b) update L1 with the new line from L2 and (c) commit the store into L1.

What happens when you add do a second write to the same cache line (to the next byte, although it turns out not to matter) in the loop? Like this:

```
top:
mov    BYTE PTR [rdx],al
mov    BYTE PTR [rdx+0x1],al
add    rdx,0x40
sub    rdi,0x1
jne    top
```

Here's a histogram of the timing for 1000 runs of the test harness for the above loop:

```
  count   cycles/itr
      1   3.0
     51   3.1
      5   3.2
      5   3.3
     12   3.4
    733   3.5
    139   3.6
     22   3.7
      2   3.8
     11   4.0
     16   4.1
      1   4.3
      2   4.4
```

So the majority of times are clustered around 3.5 cycles. That means that this additional store only added 0.5 cycles to the timing. It could be something like the store buffer is able to drain two stores to the L1 if they are in the same line, but this only happens about half the time.

Consider that the store buffer contains a series of stores like `1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3` where `1` indicates the cache line: half of the positions have two consecutive values from the same cache line and half don't. As the store buffer is waiting to drain stores, and the L1 is busily evicting to and accepting lines from L2, the L1 will come available for a store at an "arbitrary" point, and if it is at the position `1, 1` maybe the stores drain in one cycle, but if it's at `1, 2` it takes two cycles.

Note there is another peak of about 6% of results around 3.1 rather than 3.5. That could be a steady state where we always get the lucky outcome. There is another peak of around 3% at ~4.0-4.1 - the "always unlucky" arrangement.

Let's test this theory by looking at various offsets between the first and second stores:

```
top:
mov    BYTE PTR [rdx + FIRST],al
mov    BYTE PTR [rdx + SECOND],al
add    rdx,0x40
sub    rdi,0x1
jne    top
```

We try all values of `FIRST` and `SECOND` from 0 to 256 in steps of 8. The results, with varying `FIRST` values on the vertical axis and `SECOND` on the horizontal:

[image: cycles/iter for varying store offsets]

We see a specific pattern - the white values are "fast" (around the 3.0-4.1 values discussed above for the offset of 1). Yellow values are higher, up to 8 cycles, and red up to 10. The purple outliers are the highest and are usually cases where the "slow mode" described in the OP kicks in (usually clocking in a 18.0 cycles/iter). We notice the following:

- From the pattern of white cells, we see that we get the fast ~3.5 cycle result as long as the second store is in the same cache line *or the next* relative to the first store. This is consistent with the idea above that stores to the same cache line are handled more efficiently. The reason that having the second store in the next cache line works is that the pattern ends up being the same, except for the first first access: `0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, ...` vs `0, 1, 1, 2, 2, ...` - where in the second case it is the second store that first touches each cache line. The store buffer doesn't care though. As soon as you get into different cache lines, you get a pattern like `0, 2, 1, 3, 2, ...` and apparently this sucks?
- The purple "outliers" are never appear in the white areas, so are apparently restricted to the scenario that is already slow (and the slow more here makes it about 2.5x slower: from ~8 to 18 cycles).

We can zoom out a bit and look at even larger offsets:

[image: offsets up to 2048]

The same basic pattern, although we see that the performance improves (green area) as the second store gets further away (ahead or behind) the first one, up until it gets worse again at an offset of about ~1700 bytes. Even in the improved area we only get to at best 5.8 cycles/iteration still much worse than the same-line performance of 3.5.

If you add *any* kind of load or prefetch instruction that runs ahead<sup>3</sup> of the stores, both the overall slow performance and the "slow mode" outliers disappear:

[image: all good]

You can port this back to the original stride by 16 problem - any type of prefetch or load in the core loop, pretty much insensitive of the distance (even if it's *behind* in fact), fixes the issue and you get 2.3 cycles/iteration, close to the best possible ideal of 2.0, and equal to the sum of the two stores with separate loops.

So the basic rule is that stores to L2 without corresponding loads are much slower than if you software prefetch them - unless the entire store stream accesses cache lines in a *single* sequential pattern. That's contrary to the idea that a linear pattern like this never benefits from SW prefetch.

I don't really have a fleshed out explanation, but it could include these factors:

- Having other stores in the store buffers may reduce the concurrency of the requests going to L2. It isn't clear exactly when stores that are going to miss in L1 allocate a store buffer, but perhaps it occurs near when the store is going to retire and there is a certain amount of "lookhead" into the store buffer to bring locations into L1, so having additional stores that aren't going to miss in L1 hurts the concurrency since the lookahead can't see as many requests that will miss.
- Perhaps there are conflicts for L1 and L2 resources like read and write ports, inter-cache bandwidth, that are worse with this pattern of stores. For example when stores to different lines interleave, maybe they cannot drain as quickly from the store queue (see above where it appears that in some scenarios more than one store may drain per cycle).

[These comments](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/532346#comment-1916672)  by Dr. McCalpin on the Intel forums are also quite interesting.

---

<sup>0</sup> Mostly only achievable with the L2 streamer disabled since otherwise the additional contention on the L2 slows this down to about 1 line per 3.5 cycles.

<sup>1</sup> Contrast this with stores, where I get almost exactly 1.5 cycles per load, for an implied bandwidth of ~43 bytes per cycle. This makes perfect sense: the L1<->L2 bandwith is 64 bytes, but assuming that the L1 is *either* accepting a line from the L2 *or* servicing load requests from the core every cycle (but not both in parallel) then you have 3 cycles for two loads to different L2 lines: 2 cycles to accept the lines from L2, and 1 cycle to satisfy two load instructions.

<sup>2</sup> With prefetching *off*. As it turns out, the L2 prefetcher competes for access to the L2 cache when it detects streaming access: even though it always finds the candidate lines and doesn't go to L3, this slows down the code and increases variability. The conclusions generally hold with prefetching on, but everything is just a bit slower (here's a [big blob of results](https://gist.github.com/travisdowns/9a7a253b6442aa11878b9a0d79a41dd9) with prefetching on - you see about 3.3 cycles per load, but with lots of variability).

<sup>3</sup> It doesn't even really need to be ahead - prefetching several lines behind also works: I guess the prefetch/loads just quickly run ahead of the stores which are bottlenecked so they get ahead anyways. In this way, the prefetching is kind of self-healing and seems to work with almost any value you put in.

Comment: Wow! That's very interesting, good job! Can I ask a couple of side questions? 1. I guess you "plotted" the (coloured) result with a custom program, right? 2. I can't wrap my head around the first point at the very beginning of the question, how does 18B/c and 3.5c/store relate? Thank you Bee!

Comment: @MargaretBloom - no separate process is needed, I just printed the [ANSI color escapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) from the C++ code. For example, include the magic string `"\033[0;31m"` in the output and the following characters will be red. See `selectColor` in the [testing branch](https://github.com/travisdowns/bimodal-performance/blob/testing/weirdo-main.cpp#L80) - it's only a few lines of code to colorize everything. 18 cycles bytes is `64 bytes / 3.5 cycles` - here I'm calculating the throughput based on 64-byte cache lines, even if we read only a few bytes per line.

Comment: ... because in practice the limit we bump up against is probably related to how many cache-lines you store to (and in fact as noted later you can actually get the 64-byte throughput while actually storing all bytes if you do two aligned 32-byte stores which often also takes 3.5 bytes). I agree it isn't clear and I shouldn't really call that store throughput though, and there is some additional inconsistency due to my disabling prefetching for most of the remaining text. I've updated it now and I think it's clearer.

Comment: Can we rule out any kind of pipelining taking place with multiple stores to the same cache line, rather than merging in the store queue?  Even if L1D only has one write port, is it possible that eviction only requires a read port to send the line to L2, so that cycle can overlap with a 2nd store cycle?  Or is it more likely that there's a separate port that's used for reading/writing whole lines when evicting or receiving, and which locks out or takes over the normal 2x load + 1x store ports?  (In which case your data leaves HW store coalescing as the only explanation if your theory is right.)

Comment: I think it's likely there is various pipelining going on, but here are three bits of evidence to consider: (1) with two consecutive stores `F` and `S`, only if S is in the same line does it come (sometimes) "for free" and almost always "almost free". If it were just pipelining you'd expect the case where S hit some other L1-contained lined to work just as well, but the observed penalty is large (2) the observed max store throughput is 1 store/3 cycles, but the pipelining above would let you do 1 per 2 cycles. (3) while testing reads, I can read 1 cache line every 1.1. cycles (!) ...

Comment: ... which means that on most cycles both a read from the core and an incoming line from L2 are supported, which seems to contradict "lockout". OTOH that's with 1 read per line: trying to do two reads per line bumps it to two cycles. I'm not necessary saying any merging happens in the store buffer either: just that at commit it may commit more than one buffer per cycle if they are to the same line (which is different: it doesn't really save store buffer entries).

Comment: Ok, that is pretty good evidence against simply pipelining better.  And yeah, it makes sense that they still have to be tracked separately, but even being able to commit together in a single update is surprising to me, especially non-contiguous.  I wonder if pre-Skylake can commit two stores in the same cycle that aren't in the same 32B window of a line?  SKL maybe takes advantage of the design features that allow AVX512 masked stores of an entire cache line to work without a read-modify-write to commit back to back stores as a merged store.  (AVX has `vmaskmovps`...)

Comment: @PeterCordes - I mean there are other explanations too, for example stores to the same line will "hit" in the LFB so probably use less LFB resources, and this could cause a difference or various other factors. The problem is I don't have a  I also found an interesting effect with loads where loads with odd stride (in cache lines) were fast, but with even strides were slow (could have perhaps also been an associativity thing).

Comment: If you look at Dr. McCalpin's comments [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/532346#comment-1916672) starting with _One of the primary_ you'll see that he seems to imply that a primary goal of the store buffer is coalesce writes, i.e., that all writes to a single cache line may be committed in a single L1 cycle.

Comment: I don't actually think the L1 works exactly like that though (needing a RMW for L1 writes, except those of an entire cache line) because it would make writes that didn't eventually cover a cache too expensive and tests don't seem to back that up. I heard (but can't find the reference) that Intel doesn't need a RMW on L1 writes because it uses a simpler form of ECC that can be updated only based on the old value of the written bytes, the new value and the existing ECC value.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Yeah, I just replied to Dr. Bandwidth's post pointing that out.  You probably read about RMW for commit to L1D being unlikely in [my x86 byte-store answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721075/can-modern-x86-hardware-not-store-a-single-byte-to-memory), or Paul Clayton's answer [about "silent stores"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417481/what-specifically-marks-an-x86-cache-line-as-dirty-any-write-or-is-an-explici) where he says that Intel's L1D caches only use parity, not ECC, exactly because they have to handle unaligned and single-byte stores.

Answer (score 0):

Sandy Bridge has "L1 data hardware pre-fetchers". What this means is that initially when you do your store the CPU has to fetch data from L2 into L1; but after this has happened several times the hardware pre-fetcher notices the nice sequential pattern and starts pre-fetching data from L2 into L1 for you, so that the data is either in L1 or "half way to L1" before your code does its store.

Comment: Sure, but how does this relate to the question? It explains neither the weird bimodal performance, nor the overall poor performance or why the addition of an apparently unrelated read of an always-in-L1 location slows everything down by 3x or more.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: For the unrelated-load case, did you check `machine_clears.memory_ordering`?  It is possible in single-threaded code.  I forget exactly what I was doing last time I had some counts for it.  Hmm, maybe that was when some addresses were unknown until after later memory instructions might have executed.  I don't remember you mentioning that an extra load slowed it down more.

Comment: @PeterCordes I checked a lot of things, but I just double checked now and there are essentially zero MOB clears. You can get a MOB clear in single threaded code if the CPU speculates a younger load as independent of an older address-unknown store, but when the address of the store becomes know it turns out they are actually dependent. BAM, machine clear. This kind of things comes up as a problem, for e.g., in histogramming code where you are doing a bunch of loads and stores that are usually independent, but sometimes dependent.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: I didn't understand what the test harness displays (thought it was "~7.3 cycles/iteration for the first 8 iterations of the loop, then ~3.9 cycles/iteration for the later iterations"). Now it looks like the test methodology is seriously flawed (e.g. maybe more like "CPU #1 being constantly bombarded by IRQs that ruins your results, followed by being migrated to CPU #3 and getting far less IRQs that ruin the results a lot less").

Comment: @BeeOnRope: More specifically, the test harness doesn't discard "abnormally high" readings (that can be caused by CPU migrations, task switches, IRQs, SMM, ....) and on Linux IRQ balancing is often poor (often CPU #0 gets pounded while other CPUs don't - might be fun to check `/proc/interrupts`).

Comment: @Brendan - each line represents calling the asm method [`iters`](https://github.com/travisdowns/bimodal-performance/blob/master/weirdo-main.cpp#L50) times, which itself loops `output_size / stride == 4096` times (for `stride == 16`). So each line is the averaged timing for about 41 million loops.I have tried varying the loop count by two orders of magnitude each way, even timing a single loop with inline performance counters and the result is the same. Keep in mind the numbers are very (bi-)stable: usually to 1% or better, run after run - but just with two modes.

Comment: About the CPU migration: there was a good description of it in the comments on the question but someone came along and deleted them. Basically, I picked that run at random and it is atypical: _most_ runs show the phase change without also changing CPUs (I updated it to a typical run, pinned to CPU 0). I think a CPU switch _can_ cause the phase change, just like any other perturbation, and all of these statements are true at the same time based on my measurement: (A) The phase change is usually **not** associated with a CPU swtich (B) When a CPU swtich occurs, a phase change is more likely ...

Comment: (C) CPU switches usually do not cause phase changes. About interrupts causing the problem: it seem very unlikely. I checked interrupt counts with `perf` and the counts are (a) very low, about ~250 or so per second, almost all of which are timer ticks and (b) uncorrelated with interrupts (i.e., runs mostly in "slow mode" don't show a difference in interrupt numbers than those in "fast mode"). _Seriously flawed_ is a bit strong, but I'll admit it is _potentially_ seriously flawed. I can use the median to avoid outliers - but I've looked at finer-grained numbers a lot and it won't change much.