# How does the CPU load data in cache in a vector multiplication function?

Tags: c, performance, caching, cpu

Considering the following function for element-wise vector multiplication:

```
void vector_multiply(float* result, const float* a, const float* b, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result[i] = a[i] * b[i];
    }
}
```

how does the CPU load data in cache?

Since `a` and `b` are far apart in memory, does `a[i] * b[i]` require two loads?

The question comes from the fact that I've tested the same function with `a`'s data and `b`'s data interleaved to make sure that they get both put in cache when `a` is called but I haven't seen any significant difference, so I'm guessing that the multiplication in `vector_multiply` requires no more than one.

Comment: The same total amount of data has to get fetched, whether it's interleaved or not.  If it's non-interleaved, a compiler should be able to optimize it to use SIMD, for example x86 `addps` to work on 4 floats (16 bytes) of data at once. (Obviously you have to compile with optimization enabled or benchmark results are meaningless, limited by 6 or 7 cycle latency of store/reload of the integer loop counter including store-forwarding + ALU, except on CPUs like Zen 2 and 4 that do memory renaming.)  For two very small arrays, yes they could both be in the same 64-byte cache line.

Comment: As a side note, declaring these 3 pointers as `restrict` might lead to slightly better performance, if they are never overlapping anyway. But that has nothing to do with cache.

Comment: In a scenario in which the two arrays are very large, is the CPU loading 128 bytes in two different cache lines with two loads when it doesn't find `a[i]` and `b[i]`?

Comment: @Lundin, wouldn't declaring `result` as `restrict` be sufficient for better optimization?

Comment: I suggest you try a random indexing variant as well. CPUs are good at fetching sequential data. I suspect interleaving could help performance if you use the same random indexes for a and b.

Comment: Yes, if the cache line containing `a[i]` isn't already in this core's L1d cache, it will be after the load completes.  Same for the line containing `b[i]`, whether that's the same one or not.  Hardware prefetching might also pull other lines into L2 cache, e.g. Intel CPUs have a "spatial" prefetcher that will pull in the the other half of a 128-byte pair of cache line if the queue isn't already full of in-flight requests.  See also [How much of ‘What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory’ is still valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47714514) (most of it, go read the article.)

Comment: So in the interleaved case (supposing for example there are 32 bytes of `a`'s data and 32 bytes of `b`'s data) you get half of the memory loads when the data isn't already in cache but also get half of the data compared to the non-interleaved one. It's the same number of total loads in the end but there's a penalty coming from the fact that the compiler can't optimize to use SIMD, right?

Comment: @SimonGoater: You mean with random `i` and separate arrays vs. `struct { float a,b;}` so we get 1 cache miss vs. 2?  Yeah, that should prove that, especially if you update `a` in-place instead of a separate result that will also miss in cache.  But that's a totally different situation from looping over arrays to do an element-wise vector x vector product, where two separate arrays is actually *better* because modern CPUs support SIMD.

Comment: And because they have hardware prefetching, although without prefetch separate arrays would still be better since miss-under-miss non-blocking cache could overlap two misses even on an in-order CPUs, vs. missing more frequently with interleaved.  (Modern x86 CPUs with deep out-of-order exec wouldn't care much I think; with HW prefetchers  disabled, they're still doing demand loads far enough ahead.  Maybe you'd still have an effect.  And yes you can disable HW prefetchers on real hardware to run this experiment, I think there's an MSR.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Would having a third buffer, and doing something like `result[i] = a[i] + b[i] + c[i]` alter any of these considerations? To what extent can the CPU optimize the overlap of cache misses?

Comment: Memory pipelining is a very big thing.  Each core in a Skylake CPU for example can track 12 outstanding cache-line transfers (pending loads and outgoing stores), and the superqueue (off-core from L2 cache) is somewhat larger, since HW prefetching can generate extra requests, or so outgoing L2 evictions can go somewhere.

Comment: See also [Why is Skylake so much better than Broadwell-E for single-threaded memory throughput?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39260020)

Comment: more about memory-level parallelism: [For-loop efficiency: merging loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51021262) discusses some details around loops that have multiple input/output streams (looping over multiple arrays in parallel), and see some of the links in my answer there.  4 streams is totally fine.  Even 6 to 8 are also fine on modern CPUs, although if they offset from each other by multiples of 4KiB then you're likely to run into conflict misses in L1d cache.

Comment: Important background: http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/ (Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!
, essential reading for the basics of pipelined and out-of-order exec CPUs.)  And https://agner.org/optimize/ re: details of modern x86 microarchitectures like Skylake.

Answer (score 0):

> how does the CPU load data in cache?
> Since a and b are far apart in memory, does `a[i] * b[i]` require two loads?

In a scalar dot product you don't reuse any vector element, as all the products are of elements that are seen only once by the dot product routine.  So no way of reusing them, and so, no cache advantage is expected with that.  only in case you are considering to multiply matrices, then there's an advantage by doing it in boxes that fit completely in the cache, to fill as much cache memory as possible while multiplying boxes inside the matrix.

Cache access takes also advantage of parallelisim when you can make several cells to fit in a cache line (which normally is accessed in a single wide bus access, getting the effect that you ask for some data, and you also get in one read the data you are going to read next, this improves performance, as several accesses are being triggered in parallel and memory access is improved)  Spread of data is not an issue as cache lines don't require to access contiguous memory (except for the memory that fits in one cache line) allowing disperse data to be used by the cache.

But one thing you can do is to start N threads to make N products simultaneously, and passing the results of the multiplication to N-1 threads that add them together in an inverted binary tree fashion (like a set of tennis eliminatories championship) that will create a pipeline of log(N) stages that can add them efficiently, as the result of one operation is not needed for the next and many arrangements can be done in a pipeline to reordeer the addings and avoid bubbles to slow down the pipeline. A simple operation like:

```
    sum += 1;
```

makes all the sums serialized, filling the pipelines with bubbles that slow it down.  if you instead give each pair of elements a non dependency by, let's say:

```
c[0] = a[0] * b[0];
c[1] = a[1] * b[1];
...
c[N-1] = a[N-1] * b[N-1];
/* then... */
d[0] = c[0] + c[1];
d[1] = c[2] + c[3];
...
d[(N-1) / 2] = c[N/2 - 1] + c[N/2]; /* use literals instead of expressions */
/* then... */
c[0] = d[0] + d[1];
...
c[something] = c[2 * something] + c[2 * something + 1];
/* and finally */
d[0] = c[0] + c[1];
```

and you add all of them until you have all of them added together, then no dependencies between instructions exist and instructions can be started immediately without having to wait for some result to be available in the pipeline, resulting in a very fast adding sequence.

Comment: Given two arrays of 1 million floats, you wouldn't actually start a million threads to do a dot product!  Not on a normal CPU architecture anyway, where a "thread" means an OS thread.  Maybe on a GPU where a "thread" is much lighter weight.  But yes conceptually you want more instruction-level parallelism than the latency x bandwidth product of your FP add or FMA unit.

Comment: For example Skylake runs float FMA with 4 cycle latency, but 2 per clock throughput, so you need at least 8 FMAs in flight to bottleneck on throughput, not latency.  (And those are SIMD vectors of 32 bytes each...)  For a dot product, 2 loads per FMA is the actual bottleneck, and storing temporary results back to memory (even with cache-blocking for a small buffer so it hits in L1d cache) would potentially make things worse.  Normally you just unroll *some*, not full pairwise summation.  See [Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45113527) for details.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I know, I work on that.