# What is causing the store latency in this program?

Tags: c, x86-64, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization, micro-architecture

Given the following C program (MSVC does not optimize away the "work" for me, for other compilers you may need to add an `asm` statement):

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10000

typedef struct {
    int32_t a, b, c;
} Struct;

void do_work(Struct* data) {
    int32_t* a = malloc(sizeof(int32_t) * SIZE),
        * b = malloc(sizeof(int32_t) * SIZE),
        * c = malloc(sizeof(int32_t) * SIZE);

    int32_t* a_ptr = a, * b_ptr = b, * c_ptr = c;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++, a_ptr++, b_ptr++, c_ptr++, data++) {
        *a_ptr = data->a;
        *b_ptr = data->b;
        *c_ptr = data->c;
    }

    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);
}

int main() {
    Struct* data = malloc(sizeof(Struct) * SIZE);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        data[i].a = i;
        data[i].b = i;
        data[i].c = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
        do_work(data);
    }

    free(data);
}
```

**Edit:** Disassembly of `do_work()`:

```
do_work PROC                        ; COMDAT
$LN12:
    mov QWORD PTR [rsp+8], rbx
    mov QWORD PTR [rsp+16], rbp
    mov QWORD PTR [rsp+24], rsi
    push    rdi
    sub rsp, 32                 ; 00000020H
    mov rbx, rcx
    mov ecx, 40000              ; 00009c40H
    call    QWORD PTR __imp_malloc
    mov ecx, 40000              ; 00009c40H
    mov rsi, rax
    call    QWORD PTR __imp_malloc
    mov ecx, 40000              ; 00009c40H
    mov rbp, rax
    call    QWORD PTR __imp_malloc
    mov r10, rsi
    lea rcx, QWORD PTR [rbx+8]
    sub r10, rax
    mov r11, rbp
    sub r11, rax
    mov rdi, rax
    mov r8, rax
    mov r9d, 10000              ; 00002710H
    npad    6
$LL4@do_work:
    mov edx, DWORD PTR [rcx-8]
    lea rcx, QWORD PTR [rcx+12]
    mov DWORD PTR [r10+r8], edx
    lea r8, QWORD PTR [r8+4]
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rcx-16]
    mov DWORD PTR [r11+r8-4], eax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rcx-12]
    mov DWORD PTR [r8-4], eax
    sub r9, 1
    jne SHORT $LL4@do_work
    mov rcx, rsi
    call    QWORD PTR __imp_free
    mov rcx, rbp
    call    QWORD PTR __imp_free
    mov rcx, rdi
    mov rbx, QWORD PTR [rsp+48]
    mov rbp, QWORD PTR [rsp+56]
    mov rsi, QWORD PTR [rsp+64]
    add rsp, 32                 ; 00000020H
    pop rdi
    rex_jmp QWORD PTR __imp_free
do_work ENDP
```

Here's a godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/nWTPfKPd6.

(I have a similar program in Rust with the same conclusions).

Intel VTune reports that this program is 63.1% memory bound, and 52.4% store bound, with store latency of 26%. It recommends to search for false sharing, but I fail to see how there could be false sharing here. There is no concurrency, all data is owned by one core, the access patterns should be easily predicted and prefetched. I don't see why the CPU needs to stall on the stores here.

I thought that maybe the low and high bits of the addresses of the three allocations are the same and that causes them to be mapped to the same cache lines, but I remember reading that modern CPUs don't just drop some bits to assign a cache line but do more complex calculations.

Another thought was that maybe after the allocations are freed the CPU is still busy flushing the stores, and in the next run they are assigned the same address (or a close one) by the allocator and that brings problems for the CPU as it has to wait before storing new data. So I tried to not free the allocations, but that caused the code to be much slower.

I'm on Windows 11, laptop Intel Core i9-13900HX, 32 logical cores, 8 Performance Cores and 16 Efficient Cores.

Comment: Adding [x86-64] to summon the x86 optimization gods watching that tag. Good luck!

Comment: *"I fail to see how there could be false sharing here"* - I think that's just a random helpful suggestion, doesn't necessarily apply to you. *"all data is owned by one core"* - you don't seem to pin the program to one core, are you? It could be moving around different cores depending on kernel scheduling (specially for a CPU bound task like this one). I don't think that would make much of a difference, but still, have you also tried pinning it to one core? Also, you are compiling with optimizations turned on, right?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I compiled with optimizations of course. I'll try pinning to one core, by I don't think this is the reason. OS don't move between cores just because.

Comment: Also, as an experiment, maybe have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37092/3889449). What happens if you use 3 MOVNTQ inside the loop (you will need an `asm` statement) instead of the (I suppose) 3 normal MOVQ?

Comment: Aren't you really asking why is MSVC's optimisation so poor? This whole thing should be optimised out of existence as there's no output.

Comment: @SimonGoater I have the same thing in Rust (there I put `black_box()`, I just didn't bother with inline assembly), and it performs the same, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Maybe add the disassembled `do_work()` function to the question. That seems relevant enough. It is indeed true that a decent compiler would just turn the entire function into a `ret`.

Comment: You only malloc once for a repeat loop of 50k passes of reading + writing the same data.  Which is good, otherwise you'd be measuring page-fault cost for writing untouched pages, assuming your allocations were big enough that `free` decided to give the pages back to the OS instead of putting them on a free list.  ([Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987)).  So I don't get why you're mentioning what might be happening around free and the next allocation.  Do you mean between runs?

Comment: @PeterCordes that is probably referring to the 3 malloc + 3 free inside `do_work()`, not the initial malloc of the source data that is indeed only done once.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Oh I missed that.  Holy crap, so this benchmark depends a *lot* on how the malloc/free implementation handles allocations of that specific size.  For sizes above a threshold, performance will fall off a cliff (and spend much of the total time in the OS's page-fault handler, which will leave a few pages hot in cache for user-space after its done zeroing them, if like Linux it doesn't keep a pool of zeroed pages that would be cold in cache.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Tested with multiple sizes, even 800 bytes which no allocator should return to the OS, and there is still 28.6% store bound and the hotspot is still the read/write (replaced the allocator to mimalloc, because the default allocator is terrible on Windows).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Added the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's an already accepted answer. But @user23919330 was onto something. The most obvious idea would be to convert this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++, a_ptr++, b_ptr++, c_ptr++, data++) {
    *a_ptr = data->a;
    *b_ptr = data->b;
    *c_ptr = data->c;
}
```

To this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    a_ptr[i] = data[i].a;
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    b_ptr[i] = data[i].b;
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    c_ptr[i] = data[i].c;
}
```

That is, let each read and write from sequential addresses. Take advantage of caching.  Trying this out now....

**Update**. I modified OP's code such that it would run multiple times and it would print the timings (in milliseconds)

```
int testrun() {
    DWORD start, end;
    Struct* data = malloc(sizeof(Struct) * SIZE);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        data[i].a = i;
        data[i].b = i;
        data[i].c = i;
    }

    start = GetTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
        do_work(data);
    }
    end = GetTickCount();

    printf("%u\n", end - start); // print the number of milliseconds

    free(data);
}

int main() {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        testrun();
    }
}
```

Compiled for release and got these run times:

5344
5953
5438
5718
5282
4531
4578
4609
4532
4500

Or just about 5 seconds on average per test test runs.  Now let's see what happens when I change `do_work` to be this:

```
void do_work(Struct* data) {
    int32_t* a = malloc(sizeof(int32_t) * SIZE),
        *b = malloc(sizeof(int32_t) * SIZE),
        *c = malloc(sizeof(int32_t) * SIZE);

    int32_t* a_ptr = a, *b_ptr = b, *c_ptr = c;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        a_ptr[i] = data[i].a;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        b_ptr[i] = data[i].b;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        c_ptr[i] = data[i].c;
    }


    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);
}
```

Recompiled and ran and got these times:

2406
2344
2328
2266
2344
2359
2266
2328
2359
2266

Or 2.3 seconds on average.  I say there's a case to be made about taking advantage of sequential addresses.

Comment: I've already tried this, and this outperforms the original code substrantially, but it's not good for me because when the size grow it loses its performance. At 10x size it is like 4x worse.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman - Take a look at the update I just made.  I've made a solid case with your example on how to optimize and reduce runtime by 50%.

Comment: But your actual production code might have way more variables disprove my hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Most likely the `int32_t * SIZE` in the `malloc` call. If you use a bit-shift like `SIZE << 2` instead, your code should be much faster and more efficient.</s>

OK, in all seriousness, `a_ptr`, `b_ptr`, and `c_ptr` are all separate blocks of memory. In your loop you are accessing one, then the other, then the other, then repeating. I hear that is like bad for cache or something, because you are jumping around in memory, instead of accessing them sequentially.

I am skeptical that, even if a human could predict that pattern, a CPU could.

Comment: The malloc is not the hot spot, as profiling shows. And even if it was, the compiler will 100% optimize multiplication of constants.

Comment: And about your edit: I don't believe this is the problem, since the access pattern is very predictable, and the CPU can predict and prefetch much more complex patterns.

Comment: Modern CPUs have set-associative caches, and HW prefetch that can track multiple access streams, so sequential access to a few arrays in a loop is totally fine.  Workloads like `a[i] = b[i] * scale + c[i]` are common and CPU architects care about running them efficiently. (e.g. the well-known STREAM benchmark: https://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/ref.html#counting .  Also, optimized matrix multiply has an access pattern of multiple read streams and a write.)  You only start running into problems with maybe 7 or 8 streams of sequential access in a loop.

Comment: Intel used to recommend limiting loops to 4 access streams (which this code has: one read and three write), but a higher number is ok on more recent CPUs; see a section in [For-loop efficiency: merging loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51021262) about loop fission vs. fusion (splitting up a loop with many streams vs. combining loops with few streams.)