# Is it possible to call a built in function from assembly in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, built-in

Considering the following assembly code loop:

```
#include <iostream>

#define ADD_LOOP(i, n, v)       \
asm volatile (                  \
    "movw %1, %%cx      ;"      \
    "movq %2, %%rax     ;"      \
    "movq $0, %%rbx     ;"      \
    "for:               ;"      \
    "addq %%rax, %%rbx  ;"      \
    "decw %%cx          ;"      \
    "jnz for            ;"      \
    "movq %%rbx, %0     ;"      \
    : "=x"(v)                   \
    : "n"(i), "x"(n)            \
    : "%cx", "%rax", "%rbx"     \
);

int main() {
    uint16_t iter(10000);
    uint64_t num(5);
    uint64_t val;

    ADD_LOOP(iter, num, val)

    std::cout << val << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is possible to call a C function (or it's machine code output) from within a loop as specified above?

for example:

```
#include <wmmintrin.h>

int main() {
    __m128i x, y;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        x = __builtin_ia32_aesenc128(x, y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Of course, yes.  It's all binary instruction code, so it can be called, (permissions/privileges etc. allowing).

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on what you want to achieve. Do you want to call C function from assembly, or do you want to invoke and intrinsic in assembly? To call a function you just need to follow C ABI for the selected platform. Intrinsics on the other hand are not functions but the way to make compiler generate some platform specific instructions (like memory barriers, atomic instructions, various vector extensions, etc.), hence they are not to be called but rather to be replaced with the assembly itself.

Comment: You're using C++. Maybe it is very C-style C++, but it is still C++.

Comment: I'll research C ABI, thanks.  I'm not an expert on what you are referring to, but I want to call an intrinsic from inside the jnz loop without leaving the asm function, if possible

Comment: yeah, I it's C++, you're right.  I just have a habit of saying C.  I'm basically just using it for std strings and what not

Comment: I understand your point, but you still need a c++ compiler, which enforces c++ and some things are different. Like that c has implicit casting from void pointers.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks

Comment: `aesenc` is an assembly instruction (for some CPUs). Can you not just use it in your asm code?

Comment: This edit turns it into a totally different question.  Now it's about debugging GNU C inline asm constraints, not about how to use `__builtin` functions from inline asm.  That should have been a new question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.  Builtin functions aren't real functions that you can call with `call`.  They always inline when used in C / C++.

For example, if you want  [`int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) to get either a `popcnt` instruction for targets with `-mpopcnt`, or a byte-wise lookup table for targets that don't support the `popcnt` instruction, you are out of luck.  You will have to `#ifdef` yourself and use `popcnt` or an alternative sequence of instructions.

---

The function you're talking about, `__builtin_ia32_aesenc128` is just a wrapper for [the `aesenc` assembly instruction](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/AESENC) which you can just use directly if writing in asm.

---

If you're writing asm instead of using C++ intrinsics (like `#include <immintrin.h>`) for performance, you need to have a look at http://agner.org/optimize/ to write more efficient asm.  e.g. use `%ecx` as a loop counter, not `%cx`.  You're gaining nothing from using a 16-bit partial register.

You could also write more efficient inline-asm constraints, e.g. the `movq %%rbx, %0` is a waste of an instruction.  You could have used `%0` the whole time instead of an explict `%rbx`.  If your inline asm starts or ends with a mov instruction to copy to/from an output/input operand, usually you're doing it wrong.  Let the compiler allocate registers for you.  See the [inline-assembly](/questions/tagged/inline-assembly) tag wiki.

**Or better, https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm**.  Code with intrinsics typically compiles well for x86.  See [Intel's intrinsics guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/): `#include <immintrin.h>` and use `__m128i _mm_aesenc_si128 (__m128i a, __m128i RoundKey)`.  (In gcc that's just a wrapper for `__builtin_ia32_aesenc128`, but it makes your code portable to other x86 compilers.)

Comment: thank you.  I'll read the links you sent about optimization.  I didn't know that about %0, and I'll look at it, but I don't think it would be a problem in my case because there are millions of instructions in the loop.  You're probably right that intrinsics compile well, but I don't mind writing the assembly and performing an actual measurement of execution time versus the C.  It probably won't be any faster but I'd like to see the measurement comparison.

Comment: @AbdulAhad: Usually C++ with intrinsics is more maintainable.  Unless you're an asm performance expert, you should probably do that.  Or if you're just experimenting with asm for fun, and want to see if you can beat the compiler, then have a look at [Why is this C++ code faster than my hand-written assembly for testing the Collatz conjecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354978/why-is-this-c-code-faster-than-my-hand-written-assembly-for-testing-the-collat).  (Hint: start with optimized compiler output and improve on that.)

Comment: Note that this answer was written before the edit that changed the question into a different one about getting the constraints + other stuff right so the OP's inline asm will compile and assemble.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to your question may be split in two parts.

It is defenetly possible to call a C function from Assembly. To do so you need to follow a calling convention (which is described in [ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI) documents) which specifies how to pass arguments and get return values. Remember that you have registers, stack and memory to move data around.

Intrinsics however even, though they look like a C function are not functions. You may look at C as a somewhat high level assembly which works on a wide variety of architectures. In some cases you want to take an advantage of your specific architecture instruction set, hence compiler provides you with the way to do so via the means of intrinsics. Each intrinsic is mapped to some architecture specific assembly instructions. So in the end of the day you do not need to call them from assembly but rather need to find the instruction itself, for instance I expect `__builtin_ia32_aesenc128` to be replaced with [AESENC](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/AESENC.html) instruction.

Comment: It's non-trivial to make function calls from an inline-asm statement.  For example, in the x86-64 System V ABI, there's a 128-byte red-zone below `rsp` which the compiler assumes you don't clobber.  So you [can't safely use `push` or `call` in 64-bit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520013/using-base-pointer-register-in-c-inline-asm/34522750).  Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380992/inline-assembly-that-clobbers-the-red-zone.

Comment: @PeterCordes Good point. Splitting the code into pure assembly and pure C across the function call boundary may be the way to go.