# Non-temporal store to bypass L1/L2 but cache in L3 to be read by another core

Tags: multithreading, assembly, caching, x86-64, cpu-cache

On x86-64 we have [movntdq](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movntdq) for "non temporal" (uncached) stores directly to main memory.  And we have [prefetcht2](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/prefetchh) to prefetch into to L3 but not L1/L2.

But can we store to L3?  It seems like this should be useful where data is produced by one core and consumed on another--there is no use putting it in L1/L2 cache on the producer core because it will never be read from there.

If the answer is that this is not supported on x86-64, I'd be curious to know if there's a specific reason it can't or shouldn't be done (e.g. it would not improve performance because of some reason I haven't thought of).

Comment: Unfortunately no, and `cldemote` isn't available yet on mainstream CPUs. (Just Tremont, I think).  This question ([CPU cache inhibition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47102784)) is looking for the exact same thing you are (store to L3).  @prl's answer there mentions cldemote, and other answers (including mine) cover other aspects.

Comment: Having a store that only updated L3 without disturbing local L1d and L2 would need a special hardware mechanism just to support it.  (And it would probably hardly get any use for a long time if introduced now).  And might only be efficient for full-line stores the way NT stores are, although I guess partial-line LFB eviction for NT stores does have to handle sending a store out towards memory with a mask of which bits are valid.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes.  It'd be fine with me if it only supported full-line stores.  `cldemote` seems like a performance optimization for the reader to see the data sooner, not for the writer to avoid L1/L2 pollution.

Comment: Unfortunately for you, there isn't anything that supports even full-line stores, sorry if I got your hopes up.  I was just thinking out loud about design challenges for a hypothetical instruction to do this. With the major one being that it's yet another kind of store that the interconnect has to know about, so it'd be additional complexity everywhere

Comment: You might get some pollution *reduction* by doing cldemote after storing a line, hopefully limiting pollution to one way in each set instead of letting pseudo-LRU eviction keep the recently written "useless" line next time you alias that set.  Full pollution avoidance is impossible, except with `movnt` which also bypasses L3.  And BTW, the usual reason people ask about doing this is to reduce cache-miss latency on the read side; I think that's the intended use-case for cldemote.

Comment: (Update: I think I was just guessing that `cldemote` would change the LRU / LFU bits, or fully evict from L1d and L2.  If it just leaves the line in shared state, it might not help with pollution at all.)