# Do fields EVER get Hoisted and cached before thread scoping by Memory Models in OOP compilers?

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, compiler-optimization, inlining

It seems to me OOP compilers may be ruled by different rules when inlining their code before simplification and hoisting.

At first, I thought that a full inlining process PLUS the hoisting process would force a hoist before the references enter the thread context.

```
static class Scope {
    private int field = 1;
    ScheduledExecutorService e = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    ScheduledExecutorService e2 = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    void write() {
        e.execute(
                () -> {
                    field = field + 3;
                    Printer.out.print("written...");
                    e.shutdown();
                }
        );
    }
    void read() {
        e2.schedule(
                () -> {
                    Printer.out.print(val() + "...read");
                    e2.shutdown();
                }
                ,
                5,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
        );
    }

    int val() {
        return field;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Printer.setAutoFlush(true); //If you use System you'll get delays, so use a flushable version.
    Scope scope = new Scope();
    scope.read();
    scope.write();
}
```

I am not particularly fluent in bytecode or processor/assembler instruction, but I will pseudocode what I believe the compiler may do...

At one point... a few steps before the code becomes completely inlined the runnable at read() may look like this.

```
() -> {
   Scope self = Scope.this;
   int cacheRead = self.val();
   Printer.out.print(cacheRead + "...read");
   e.shutdown();
}
```

Eventually the Printer class becomes unfolded, the read method itself until everything is inlined on the main() as a single sequence of instructions.

At which point, the compiler then begins to do inferences to help reduce interthread latencies, this means that every non-fenced read or write will be reordered and/or simplified.

The lines:

```
Scope self = Scope.this;
int cacheRead = self.field; //simplified to reference directly
```

Can then be simplified as:

```
int cacheRead = Scope.this.field;
```

**This would mean that at this point, such a deep inlining process would make the compiler believe that what we did was a direct integer loading.**

*(BTW .val() will also be unfolded into bytecode, then C then assembler and processor instructions...
in-between these translations the code crosses 2 reorderings, the JIT compiler reorder and the processor...)*

The thing is that, since `int` is not `volatile`, the compiler MAY infer that the integer is NOT PART of any inter-process communication... so, to prevent latency it may hoist the value outside the Runnable instantiation (in this case inside it's scope...).

```
new Runnable() {
   int cacheRead = Scope.this.field;
   @Override
   public void run() {
      Printer.out.print(cacheRead + "...read");
      e.shutdown();
   }
}
```

Creating a memory visibility issue.

NOW... this is why I believe this MAY (WILL) NOT happen...

**OOP syntax rules**

If the inlining OBEYS the syntax and rules of the language... then the hoisting will NOT damage the visibility of the memory... EVEN IF there is an attempt at doing so:

```
   new Runnable() {
       Scope cachedScope = Scope.this;
       @Override
       public void run() {
          Printer.out.print(cachedScope.field + "...read"); //This may still be subjected to latency even if a hoisting occured.
          e.shutdown();
       }
    }
```

The implication here is that OOP compilers may not go into a deep inlining before going to the hoisting/caching step... **(assuming all compilers steps are inlining -> simplification -> elimination -> hoisting in that order)**

So if the programmer DOES NOT explicitly dereferences the primitive, the thing hoisted is the Object reference, not its separated fields.

I know that if multiple checks are done on the same non-volatile field... even if done via `this.` then the hoisting of the primitive occurs at the start when the first read is performed (in these cases opqueness/memory_oreder_relaxed is required).

The Java language is somewhat explicit in this sense... IF a lambda, captures a **local** value it forces us to make it final and dereference it before entering the lambda... IF the lambda captures a field, IT DOESN'T.

THIS to me is a didactic vehicle to help us remember the difference between locals and fields... so as to make EXPLICIT that **fields will always force a shared register reading among all child scopes...**

Of course... the Java language may have control over what their JIT compilers can do... but what about the processor optimization?

We know for a fact that memory latency cannot be influenced whatsoever by any language... this means that a field being non-volatile will never affect its "visibility" as a consequence of latency... all processors are cache coherent, so this is out of the question...

So, do fields EVER get hoisted and cached before thread scoping by Memory Models in OOP compilers?

What I know for a fact because of Java documentation is that VarHandle.getOpaque() will prevent a complete inlining... on primitives... the examples never disclose object referencing.

Not only will it prevent it, but the hoisting and simplification is completely prevented.

opaqueness according to the docs resemble the "readOnce" or "memory_order_relaxed"... the issue here is that the only thing we need to prevent is even lesser than the things it prevents... we just need to prevent complete hoisting on top, before runnable creation.

I know that if this code would have a double-check, then the integer... no matter if it is a field or local, would be hoisted on top at the first line inside the runnable (NOT before its creation) making a double check impossible and the compiler would simplify it and erase it, forcing a getOpaque on every read if we really want to allow for a double check.

But in this example only ONE read is performed, so no need to make it opaque... IF memory rules apply correctly.

Comment: I suspect there's no single "answer" to this question, and it totally depends on the implementers' choices.  Not sure this is really on-topic for SO, which strongly prefers questions that can be answered.

Comment: Can I take your answer as: "You cannot rely on what the compiler will or will not cache/hoist, and should always employ reordering barriers"? ...even at the cost of an extreme diminishing in performance??

Comment: Why do you think that an opaque load would have any extra cost vs. a plain `int` read that happened not to get optimized away?  It doesn't take any special instructions to read an `int` atomically on normal CPUs, and you already need that to avoid tearing.   If you the lambda actually access the variable once per print, that possible CPU-cache miss is the cost.

Comment: (I don't know if this is an optimization that ever happens in practice, or is allowed by the language standard, but guarding against it shouldn't have any cost if Opaque works the way I expect. `volatile` would indeed cost unnecessary memory barriers or more strongly-ordered instructions on some ISAs.)

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes for the answer.
"It doesn't take any special instructions to read", 
If this plain is allowed by an Object hoisting (because the compiler hoisted the reference to the top), the Java bytecode generated, antecedes all object accesses by an invoke to an exception thrower ensuring the object is not null.
The VarHandle.getOpque will also suffer this invoke on the static method and the parameters being used inside the static method.
If the load would not be hoisted anywhere the read would incur in no extra instruction.
An Object hoist would allow a "plain" read but ...

Comment: by dereference with an extra instruction (object ref => field ref).
A call to getOpaque static method even more extra instructions.
A volatile would be the worst offender.

So...: **no hoist (true plain) > Object hoist (plain by deref) > getOpaque (relaxed) > volatile**.

BTW I know all this will eventually get simplified by the processor, but It'd be nice to have the speed from the get-go.

Comment: *get simplified by the processor* - You mean by the JIT compiler?  If the actual machine code the CPU runs has wasted work, that would be inefficient.  IDK if anything in the Java language standard lets you safely avoid getOpaque here if you want to make sure that a load happens in the optimized asm for every run of the lambda.  It's pretty much unavoidable for Java that only the final JIT-optimized machine code is actually efficient, I think.  Maybe you could save a tiny amount of startup / warmup time every run if your optimization of using plain `int` is guaranteed safe (or happens to work)

Comment: Thak you very much. Will be using opaque from now on.

Comment: 1/4... Hi, @PeterCordes After some research and testing Java's `getOpaque` seem not that good, the overhead from the casting, the invokeStatic and the runtime instrospection , the times went from 30 - 40 millis(converted from nanos) with `volatile`, to 300+ millis with opaqueness.

The times with non-volatile begins at 17 millis flat, and with full JIT-opt, they end on 3 - 1 millis.

I've tried different processors (LOCK-prefixed (Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700HQ)  and LL/SC'd (AMD Ryzen 5 5500U)) which I assume have different flavors of optimization, and NONE seem to fail on the reading ...

Comment: 2/4 ...of non-volatile non-reified fields, even on the most extreme cases of contention, the **spinning CAS** seem to never load from a cached register.

My test runs for around 1 minute, in which a full JIT optimization usually kicks in: * with `volatile`: at around the 10th iteration, while *with plain non-volaitle loads: at around the 2nd or 3rd.
With getOpaque the times never settle and have a lot more fluctuation... less consistent.

I've decided to use `getOpaque` ONLY on double-checking portions of the code, I believe this is the best use of ...

Comment: 3/4 opqueness since I've read some linux kernel documentation in which read_once() is used exactly for double-checking.

Also, when exposing the field to the outside the non-volatile is delivered via `getOpaue` wihch preventing visibility issues.

As for the details about how opaqueness differs from `volatile`, I've read and watched hours of videos, and no one seem to fully explain what is THAT which makes memory_order_relaxed OR `read_once` less intrusive than `volatile`.

My guess is that relaxed, makes the JIT-compiler enter a state in which parallel-FULLY-OPTIMIZED-and-reordered...

Comment: 4/4... instructions, are forced to deliver code directly to shared memory instead of writing them to their independent inner caches, so the "relaxed" allows parallel code to be fully reordered, BUT their stores will be "flushed" ASAP, this means that opaqueness on the loading side, may increase writing latency on the Thread writing side.

Comment: * >forced to deliver stores (not "code").

Comment: Your i7 and Ryzen are both x86-64, which doesn't have LL/SC.  I have no idea why you'd think that Java could be using LL/SC retry loops for atomic RMWs on a Ryzen CPU.  Also, neither of your CPUs support `cldemote` which would make it possible to push a store to L3 cache to reduce latency for reads by other cores.  See [Non-temporal store to bypass L1/L2 but cache in L3 to be read by another core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65801148) - x86-64 can't do the thing you're guessing it did, at least not without inserting `cldemote` instructions, but those would run as a NOP on your CPUs.

Comment: NT stores could bypass all levels of cache, but that would mean the reader misses all the way to DRAM, which is probably even slower than L3 cache having to message the core the owns the line to write it back to shared L3.

Comment: Maybe `getOpaque` doesn't optimize as well as I'd hoped, if your results are accurate.  But you're talking about runtime introspection; could that be slowing things down, at least the introspection itself from having another kind of object?

Comment: Java `volatile` is like C++ `std::memory_order_seq_cst`.  On x86, that means pure stores to it are more expensive, but pure loads are the same cost as `memory_order_relaxed`.  I'm not sure if Java `volatile` makes `num++` an atomic RMW (`lock xadd`) or just separately-atomic load and store.  Making a variable `volatile` means all accesses to it are "atomic", including from functions that only run when it's not shared.

Comment: @PeterCordes "Your i7 and Ryzen are both x86-64"... this is embarrassing... lol.
I saw some improvement on the Ryzen one after weakCAS, so I guess that made me forget it wasn't x86, I think I may have done other changes simultaneously that made me believe it was the weakCAS refactor.
As for the LL/SC performance VS LOCK-prefixed from what I understand x86 is a beast when dealing with mathematical operations because ADD and INC are a type of atomic update that the processor performs on it's own, but in cases in which a CAS operation requires more "complexity" like re-capturing instance...

Comment: state to recompute the update, then a weakCAS is better since it will not "bubble wait" until acquiring cache exclusivity.

Comment: on x86, CAS_weak compiles exactly the same as CAS_strong, to a single `lock cmpxchg` or `lock cmpxchg16` instruction.  Either way you need to use CAS in a retry loop to emulate `.fetch_or` if you use the return value, for example, or to do an atomic shift (`lock shr` isn't supported in hardware), or atomic FP add (CAS the bit-pattern after `movq rcx, xmm0`)

Comment: As for the L3 cache direct storage, I completely agree there is no way that a semantic could force a direct flush, this goes back to a previous statement on another question were I said "Processors give no way to speed-up or delay their Cache Coherency Protocols" so, NO the language providing such "direct flushing" would not be possible.
I was watching a C++ keynote speak and the flushing behavior was mentioned, but that's all... I was just confused.
After more thought I think `memory_order_relaxed` loads... and by extension Java's `getOpaque` impose a SELF non-reordering ...

Comment: behavior, while `volatile` loads, enforce non-reordering ON the writes performed by OTHER concurrent sequences of instructions, so that would be the difference...(?)