# If I create dma mapping then does prefetch function fetches data from the device DMA mapped area and populate area to hold whats read from mapped area

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, dma, network-driver

I like to know how linux function prefetch works

It is defined as

```c
    #ifndef ARCH_HAS_PREFETCH
    #define prefetch(x) __builtin_prefetch(x)
    #endif
```

so in drivers this can be found

```c
        rx_buf = page_address(tp->Rx_databuff[entry]);//Rx_databuff[] are Page type array
        dma_sync_single_for_cpu(d, addr, pkt_size, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
        prefetch(rx_buf);
        skb_copy_to_linear_data(skb, rx_buf, pkt_size);
```

So rtl 8139 device has 256 Rx descriptors. and addr parameter to dma_sync_single_for_cpu is I think enables reading from device and save the data in some temporary memory(what is this memory area?) and so `prefetch` I think is just reading that memory area and populating the rx_buf from that memory area.

I wish I could see `__builtin_prefetch(x)` defination but I could not find it so what's going on with prefetch call can anyone please tell me this

Comment: It is just a hint that you are likely to use some memory, so try to load it into cache.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460563/builtin-prefetch-how-much-does-it-read  It hopefully does nothing on uncacheable memory areas.

Comment: DMA sync API in reality are cache flushes (they also handle bounce buffers when it’s the case). And note, that these flushes are architecture dependent, e.g. on x86 they are no-ops (except bounce buffers case).